# Is there a name for words which fit all four of the given lexical categories?

Tags: lexicon, category

This question is Inspired by a practice exam question which is provided below. (Please note **I'm not asking for answers to the exam question**, as I provided my own)

> Use the word *fast* in sentences in the lexical category and function indicated. Each example should be UNAMBIGUOUS. **Inflection permitted**
>
> A. noun/nominal - my answer: We went on a fast.
>
> B. verb/verb - my answer: He is fasting over the holiday.
>
> C. adjective/adjectival - my answer: My car is faster.
>
> D. adverb/adverbial - my answer: The ball bounced fast.

Is there a category/name/group for words which fit all four of the given lexical categories, as exemplified above? To clarify, I'm asking this question so I can search for words inside the group/category which can be used with this question as it contains words which meet the four required categories, for further studying on my own.

Comment: Free. Inflected to freebie.

Comment: No, there is no special name. Most English words can be used as any of the open POS categories -- noun, verb, adjective, adverb. Prepositions and conjunctions are not out of the question, either. That's just the kind of language English is -- an analytic language without much inflection; POS is more important in inflected languages.

Comment: There is a duplicate on ELL: [What word describes words that can be more that one part of speech?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179117/what-word-describes-words-that-can-be-more-that-one-part-of-speech)